# Cut holes into OpenLayers3 polygons (subtract)

Tags: openlayers-3, polygons

The old version of OpenLayers supports cutting holes into polygons. See [donut example](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/donut.html).

I am unable to find [examples](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/examples/) or [documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/apidoc/) regard this feature for OpenLayers3.

How do I cut holes into OpenLayers3 polygons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the appendLinearRing(linearRing) function. http://openlayers.org/en/v3.3.0/apidoc/ol.geom.Polygon.html#appendLinearRing